# Como faço pra verificar se uma STRING possui mais de 3 caracteres?

Tags: python, string, funções, loop

preciso verificar se uma string tem mais de 3 caracteres, como faço isso?

Já tentei assim:

```py
nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
a = [i for i in enumerate(nome)]
print([i for i, y in a])
if a > 3:
    print('Válido!')
else:
    print('Inválido!')
```

Está dando erro:

````py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hyago/projetos/exerciciosPythonBrasil/EstruturaDeRepeticao/ex3.py", line 4, in <module>
    if a > 3:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'```

Como resolvo isso?
````

Comment: `a` é uma lista de tuples. Você não pode comparar isso a um inteiro. Para verficar se um nome tem mais de 3 caracteres basta fazer `len(nome)>3`

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas, isso me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazer uma operação > entre um int e uma list não faz sentido.

Se me lembro bem para fazer isso em python seria:

```
if len(a) > 3:
```